# SWT Global KeyListener Button Focus Problem

Tags: java, swt

for my app I need the space key to call a function independent from the focused widget, everywhere in the app but only if the according tab is opend. I found that one can add a filter to the display, like this:

```
 getShell().getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

            public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
                if( arg0.character == 32 ) { /**SPACE*/
                    if( mainTabs.getSelection().equals(analyseSoundFilesTab)) {
                        soundController.playButtonClickHandler();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

That works fine most of the time, but if I give a button the focus via the "tab" or "shift tab", its kinda strange - the space bar will than activate a "button pressed", as if one clicks the button with the mouse. Im a bit stuck now, I don't know how to avoid this...
For the buttons, I have implemented a SelectionListener.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TraverseListener and disabled press event detection using doin field. Here is a sample code:

```
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if (e.character == 32) {
            System.out.printf("Space detected %s\n", e);
        }
    }
});

Button b1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
b1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent se) {
        System.out.printf("Button pressed %s\n", se);
    }
});

b1.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent te) {
        System.out.printf("Traverse detected %s\n", te);
        te.doit = true;
    }
});
```

If `addTraverseListener()` didn't exist, your space button was detected after filter, so you would see "Space detected..." and after that "Button pressed...". Now that you set `te.doit = true`, you say to SWT to do space bar traversal (which does nothing actually) instead of firing key listener. You may optionally check te.detail to only prevent mnemonic traversals.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing the 'Space key' is the real problem, because it is a general feature in most (all?) OS's that pressing space is equal to selecting the widget that has focus.

A way out would be using subclassed `Button` widgets that ignoring Space.

But it would confuse a lot of users, just because they expect that a focussed button is selected when they hit space and do not expect some other action.

Comment: To make clear what I want: Maybe you know the tool CoolEdit. They have the "play file" functon on the spacebar, and my chef also wants it that way. You are right, it will mix up the standard way. :/