# SWT Actions with Keyboard Shortcuts... without having to add them to the menu

Tags: swt, action, toolbar, jface, menubar

We currently have implemented a lot of SWT Actions, because it is a nice way to bind a single command to be added to the menubars and toolbars, and to have Keyboard Shortcuts for these commands.

Now... how can I register an Action in plain SWT/JFace without having to add it to a menubar, but in a way that it still can be called by a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to solve this in plain SWT by using `Display.addFilter` on the `KeyDown` event. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476076/swt-global-keylistener-button-focus-problem) for an example.

Comment: Okey, I know about this technique, but I wondered if there is something better. But since no one answers... here you go.

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.eclipse.ui.bindings extension, and add a new key.

You assign the *sequence* (M1, M2, M3, and M4 are used to represent keys like Shift, Command, and Alt, depending on the system). For example, I have assigned Alt+D as my key combo for a command, so I entered "M3+D" in the sequence field.

To get your key binding to work, you'll need to pick a *schemeId*. You could make one under the bindings extension. Just assign it an ID. Then you need to add an entry to the "plugin_customization.ini" file:

```
org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=your.binding.scheme.id
```

Or you could just use the "org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" as your scheme ID, but that includes a lot of Eclipse's key combos, which will override yours I think.

You can leave the *contextId* field blank, it says it will default to org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window in that case.

Finally, just specify the ID of your command, and you should be set!

Comment: This works in a standalone SWT/JFace application? Do I have to add special jars?

Comment: Oh, what I described is how you do it with an Eclipse RCP application. Sorry, I'm not sure of the preferred way to go about doing this in a standalone app.