# Using IAction::setAccelerator does not work as expected

Tags: swt, jface

I face an issue regarding keyboard shortcuts using JFace IAction and `setAccelerator()`. My sample code:

```java
menuAction.setAccelerator(SWT.CTRL | 'A');
```

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>CtrlL+A</kbd> is not recognised within my application.

Comment: Is this just an SWT+JFace application or is it part of an Eclipse plugin?

Comment: It is just jface (swt)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the accelerator property of an `IAction` only carries the information which key shortcut should be used.

The actual implementation that captures key shortcuts and executes matching actions is not part of JFace or at least not active by default. Some bits and pieces that are part of Platform/UI make it work in the workbench.

To see what is actually needed to make accelerators work in a standalone JFace application, you should follow the call to `ExternalActionManager.ICallback::isAcceleratorInUse()` in `ActionContributionItem` ~ line 825.

If this doesn't lead to a solution, you can still add a display filter to invoke the respective actions for a key shortcut (see also [SWT Actions with Keyboard Shortcuts... without having to add them to the menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244948/swt-actions-with-keyboard-shortcuts-without-having-to-add-them-to-the-menu)).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add this action `menuAction` to your menu manager and after applying all you stuffs you must to update the menu manager. Call `updateAll(true)` method on your menu manager. This update is required because the menu manager didn't notice your accelerator assignment yet!