# Registerring Hot keys in java SWT

Tags: java, swt, hotkeys

I am designing a java app using SWT.I want to add a global key listener to this app so that when CTRL+'A' is pressed, it prints "the app is running"(This is just an example) .That is i want to register hot key for this app.I have tried this code

```
public class HkeyDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display=new Display();
        Shell shell=new Shell(display);

        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if (e.character == 0x01) {
                    System.out.printf("Space detected %s\n", e);
                }
            }
        });

        Button b1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        b1.setText("hello");
        b1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent se) {
                System.out.printf("Button pressed %s\n", se);
            }
        });



        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();

    }

}
```

I have taken this code from 
[SWT Global KeyListener Button Focus Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476076/swt-global-keylistener-button-focus-problem)

But it doesnt seem to work when app is not in focus.I want it to work even when app is not in focus.How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking for a solution,You can use JIntellitype if you want a windows specific solution.It directly enable you  to  register global hot keys.And in case you need a platform independent solution,you can use Jnativehook , which will not directly help you in registering global hot keys but you can add global listeners to your app using which you can implement hot keys.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such solution globally (across all running applications on your system) using SWT. You will need to use platform-specific native code.